# Using var as global in C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Convert(string word)
{
    var dictionary = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dictionaryJson.text);

    if(dictionary[word] != null)
    {
        dictionary[word].ToObject<VocabularyModel>();
        // do something;
    }
    else
    {
        // do something;
    }
}
```

I am using `(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert json to `var dictionary`. Everything works fine. However I only have 1 json file and every time a use the function I have to:

```
var dictionary = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dictionaryJson.text);
```

Is there any way to call that line only one and the `var dictionary` is saved as global variable or something similar that help me call the above command only one time only.

And one other question: does the `dictionary[word]` works like a loop in an array? Does it go through the dictionary one by one and search for the key "[word]" ?

Comment: You can store the dictionary as a class scope variable of whatever holds the "Convert" function. I advise not to make any variable global here. Globals are bad idea for anything but compile time or runtime constants. And especialyl for sharing data that might change. At best I would make a global variable of type "ClassThatHoldsConvert" that you can assign differnet instances too. Wich then only has to build that Dictionary on teh first try.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the declaration of into a class-level scope.

```
class WhatEverYourClassNameIs
{
    private var dictionary;

    // Deserializing in constructor, but you can do it elsewhere
    WhatEverYourClassNameIs()
    {
        dictionary = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dictionaryJson.text);
    }
    void Convert(string word)
    {
        // This function and all other functions within your class will have access to dictionary
    }
}
```

Regarding your second question, I don't have a concrete answer since the documentation doesn't say so. A normal .NET dictionary has O(1) indexing complexity, meaning that it doesn't take longer the more elements you have in the dictionary. If you want to be certain you'd have to look up the source code and see how indexing is accomplished in the JObject class

Comment: can not man. beacause "var" only appear with thin a local variable.
:v if it was that easy i would not ask :)

Comment: Ah, right. You're casting to JObject, so can't you just use that as a type instead?